# Recursively store parent nodes' titles up to root

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I've got a table that looks like this: [image: table].

So, any entry that is not a folder has a corresponding input tag. Right now I'm setting the `name` attribute for the inputs in the `renderColumn` method, like this:

```
const node = data.node;
const $tdList = $(node.tr).find('>td');

if (node.isFolder()) {
  $tdList.eq(1).empty();
} else {
  const $input = $tdList.eq(1).find('input');
  $input.attr('name', `${node.parent.title}_${node.title}`);
  $input.attr('value', node.data.value);
}
```

but what it does is effectively storing only the parent's title. Is there any way I could recursively store all the parents' titles up to root, so that, for example, in `version` column I had `input[name="categoryCell__version"]`, then in `backgroundColor` — `categoryCell_configuration_backgroundColor`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it recursively.

```
function buildTitle(node) {
  if (node.parent.className !== 'alex-node`) { // just an example, change the condition to something else
    return '';
  } else {
    return buildTitle(node.parent) + node.parent.title + '__';
  }
}
```

(you'll need to trim the underscores, but it's rather simple)